# How to access audio from IP Webcam?

Tags: python, python-requests

[IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) streams the phone's camera to a locally hosted webpage. You can access the videofeed and audio through <ip>/video and <ip>/audio.wav respectively. For some reason you cannot do requests.get() on either of those urls. For video, you can use cv2.VideoCapture() instead, but I haven't found any way to get the audio yet.

The audio is a continuously longating .wav file and is easily accessible inside a browser, so how come requests.get() won't work on it? The request just loads indefenitely and doesn't return.

Comment: a `.get` will wait for the entire response before returning. This will not work for streams because there is no end to the response. You might be able to get the stream data by setting the `stream=True` option as described [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

Comment: Thanks, `stream=True` helped get a response. But I can't save it to a file, it just keeps on writing indefenitely. Had no luck transcribing it to a file yet.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use a virtual audio endpoint, such as [VB Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/), specify the output of your browser to be through VB Cable, and then capture the output of that with the sounddevice module. It would be way better to find an actual solution though.